# Find last time application was opened. Check if older than 30 days

Tags: bash, macos

I'm trying to write a script that tells me when the last time a specific application (On Mac OSX) was opened and then see if its been longer than 1 month.

I'm able to find how long ago by using 'mdls' on the Mac. And then I am able to find what the date was 1 month ago, but now I'm a bit stuck on how to write the IF statement.

```
#!/bin/sh

outlook_last_opened=`mdls "/Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Outlook.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Outlook" -name kMDItemLastUsedDate | awk '{print $3}'`

last_month_day=`date -v -1m '+%Y-%m-%d'`  # Sets the date to 1 month ago

if [[ {???} ]]; then                      # Not sure about this
  echo "Older than 1 month"
else
  echo "Less than 1 month"
fi
```

Comment: Can you also provide the format of `outlook_last_opened` so those of us on Linux can also try to assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this bash function which will convert a YYYY-MM-DD date into a timestamp since the epoch (it will keep the current time of day):

```
date_to_timestamp() { date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' "$1" '+%s'; }
```

You can then convert your 2 values and compare them:

```
if [ $(date_to_timestamp $outlook_last_opened) -lt $(date_to_timestamp $last_month_day) ]; then
  echo "Older than 1 month"
else
  echo "Less than 1 month"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! That was perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could...

```
[[ $(( $(date -d"$outlook_last_opened" +%s) - $(date -d"$last_month_day" +%s) )) -gt 0 ]]
```

But I don't know... I'm using GNU/Linux, not OSX

Comment: consider doing a straight `A -gt B` instead of `A - B -gt 0`